# Python numpy: Efficiently get rows containing min value of column for each unique tuple of 3 other columns

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, indexing, unique

I have some data stored in an list of lists (a list of ~200,000 rows x 6 columns).

I need to get the following subset of the data:
For each unique set of values in columns [1,2,4], I need to find the row with the minimum value of column 0 and keep only that row.

I have to do this in old numpy 1.10 (don't ask...), so there's no 'axis=0' option in np.unique().

The following example runs and produces the correct output, but is painfully slow. This seems so basic, so I feel that the (lack of) speed must be my fault.

```
# S-L-O-W way to get the desired output:
import numpy as np

# Example dataset
data = [[1, 1, 1, 'a', 1],
        [0, 1, 1, 'b', 1],
        [0, 3, 1, 'c', 4],
        [3, 1, 1, 'd', 1],
        [4, 3, 1, 'e', 4]]

desired_output = [[0, 1, 1, 'b', 1],
                  [0, 3, 1, 'c', 4]]

# Currently coding on a geriatric machine with numpy pre-version 1.13 and no ability to upgrade,
# so np.unique() won't take an axis argument. The next few hack lines of code get around this with strings...
tuples_str = []
tuples_raw = [[datarow[jj] for jj in [1,2,4]]  for datarow in data ]
for datarow in data:
    one_tuple = [datarow[jj] for jj in [1,2,4]]
    tuples_str.append( '_'.join([str(ww) for ww in one_tuple]) )

# Numpy unique on this data subset with just columns [1,2,4] of original data
unq, unq_inv, unq_cnt = np.unique(tuples_str, return_inverse=True, return_counts=True)

# Storage
output = []

# Here's the painfully slow part:
# Iterate over each subset of data where rows take the value in one unique tuple (i.e. columns [1,2,4] are identical)
for ii, idx in enumerate(np.unique(unq_inv)):

    # Get the rows that have the same values in columns [1,2,4]
    all_matches_thistuple = [row for ii, row in enumerate(data) if unq_inv[ii]==idx]

    # Find the index of the row with the minimum value for column 0
    first_line_min_idx = np.argmin([int(row1[0]) for row1 in all_matches_thistuple])

    # Save only that row
    output.append(all_matches_thistuple[first_line_min_idx])
print(output)
```

Comment: Can you finesse this with appropriate application of `groupby`?

Comment: The requirement given in the second paragraph sounds like something that is a one-liner in Pandas (your data also matches a Dataframe format). I guess Pandas is out of the question, even for a local (user-only) installation?

Comment: I don't have access to Pandas on this machine (which I agree is ridiculous). I could possibly do a user-only install. I was hoping that numpy had something fast that would suffice, but if someone has a pandas one-liner then I'll get to work on making Pandas happen.

Comment: Pandas solution [for reference]: `df.sort_values(0).drop_duplicates([1, 2, 4])`

Comment: You can do this in plain Python very effectively. I don't understand why you are even using `numpy` here, but in any even, I've posted two very performant solutions that require only the Python standard lib.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are *starting* with a list-of-lists, you can use plain Python to accomplish this easily and it will be performant. Indeed, you are using `numpy` with `object` dtype, so I suspect you are gaining very little in performance using the built-in routines, since you lose data-locality (and are essentially left with the equivalent of crappy Python `list` objects). Instead, you can accomplish this in linear time (not counting an initial sort of the data, which will be O(n*logN), but it will be using Python's timsort, so it will effectively be *very* fast), doing only a couple passes on the data:

```
In [1]: data = [[1, 1, 1, 'a', 1],
   ...:         [0, 1, 1, 'b', 1],
   ...:         [0, 3, 1, 'c', 4],
   ...:         [3, 1, 1, 'd', 1],
   ...:         [4, 3, 1, 'e', 4]]
   ...:

In [2]: from operator import itemgetter

In [3]: group_key = itemgetter(1,2,4)

In [4]: data.sort(key=group_key)
```

Then simply:

```
In [6]: first = itemgetter(0)

In [7]: result = []

In [8]: from itertools import groupby
   ...: for _, g in groupby(data, group_key):
   ...:     result.append(min(g, key=first))
   ...:

In [9]: result
Out[9]: [[0, 1, 1, 'b', 1], [0, 3, 1, 'c', 4]]
```

An alternative approach builds an auxiliarry data-structure using a `defaultdict`. This is the idiomatic way to group non-sorted data. This might be useful if you want to be able to keep these values grouped:

```
In [10]: from collections import defaultdict

In [11]: grouper = defaultdict(list)

In [12]: data = [[1, 1, 1, 'a', 1],
    ...:         [0, 1, 1, 'b', 1],
    ...:         [0, 3, 1, 'c', 4],
    ...:         [3, 1, 1, 'd', 1],
    ...:         [4, 3, 1, 'e', 4]]

In [13]: for row in data:
    ...:     _,x,y,_, z = row
    ...:     grouper[(x,y,z)].append(row)
    ...:

In [14]: grouper
Out[14]:
defaultdict(list,
            {(1, 1, 1): [[1, 1, 1, 'a', 1],
              [0, 1, 1, 'b', 1],
              [3, 1, 1, 'd', 1]],
             (3, 1, 4): [[0, 3, 1, 'c', 4], [4, 3, 1, 'e', 4]]})

In [15]: first = itemgetter(0)

In [16]: [min(group, key=first) for group in grouper.values()]
Out[16]: [[0, 1, 1, 'b', 1], [0, 3, 1, 'c', 4]]
```

Comment: Thanks for posting. When I run solution 1, I am getting an name error: 'first' is not defined at this line:  result.append(min(g, key=first)).

Comment: @cataclysmic yes, sorry, forgot to copy the following line: `In [6]: first = itemgetter(0)`

Comment: I like the `collections.defaultdict` method, but note you might see a memory usage spike for large datasets.

Comment: @jpp almost certainly not in this case. Note, *no* sublists are copied. The only things being moved around under the hood are machine-word sized pointers

Comment: I thought hashing logic might be expensive if you had a large number of groups..but since you only have 999 max here you *may* be fine.

Comment: @jpp what do you mean, exactly?  I would expect this to still be fast even with a lot of groups. Python `dict` objects are *extremely* optimized and performant.

Comment: Both solutions work for me with the 'first = ...' line, and both are obviously far faster and more elegant than my original hack method. I really appreciate it!

Comment: @cataclysmic both of these approaches are very common Python idioms. The `groupby` method can be *extremely* space efficient if the data is already sorted, especially.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, [Source](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.co.uk/2014/09/why-does-my-100mb-file-take-2gb-of.html): "The only difference is that instead of 200K lists, you have 200K dicts. A dict is bigger because each slot in a dict has to hold a hash value, a key pointer, and a value pointer, instead of just a value pointer. They need more slack than lists (because they're more expensive to copy when they expand, because you have to reprobe every hash instead of just copying a big buffer of memory, and because hash tables work best with specific types of numbers for their capacity)."

Comment: @jpp that is only a problem for creating **many small dicts** not one large one. Especially on Python > 3.6, which has optimized the space used for a `dict` (now keeping a sparse array of indices, and a dense array of values, which is how it maintains insertion order btw)

Comment: While the extent of the issue is reduced, I believe the logic is still true. As I said, for a small number of groups, it's probably not a problem (esp. in 3.6+).

Comment: @jpp which is btw, why you shouldn't use `dict` objects as a record-type, that is what `tuple` objects, especially `namedtuple` objects are for.

Comment: By the way, I just timed the first method on a sizable sample (1/10) of my dataset and it's nearly instantaneous, versus well over an hour for my original slow implementation.

Comment: @jpp no, the logic is not the same at all. The problem is that each individual `dict` has a lot of overhead, but as the size of the dict grows, the cost of this overhead is becomes a small fraction of the overall size of the data-structures. Even in <= 3.6, a `dict` is a *perfectly fine and optimized* data-structure for storing very, very large maps.

Answer (score 2):

This is one way with Pandas if you can get it working:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data).sort_values(0).drop_duplicates([1, 2, 4]).values
```

**Result**

```
[[0 1 1 'b' 1]
 [0 3 1 'c' 4]]
```

**Explanation**

Your problem can be reduced to:

- Sort by column 0, `ascending=True` is the default.
- Remove duplicate rows by columns [1, 2, 4].
- `pd.DataFrame.values` extracts the underlying numpy array.

Comment: Thank you for posting this line & explanation!